# camel jdbc and outputClass option

Tags: apache-camel, bindy, camel-jdbc

I want to read from DB and create a CSV file. In order to do that I am using **camel-jdbc** and **camel-bindy**.

First I set the body with the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT  [vendor],
        [ean],
        [itemid] AS itemId,
        [quantity]
FROM [dbo].[ElectronicDeliveryNotes]
```

then I call the jdbc component

```
<to uri="jdbc:dataSource?outputType=SelectList&amp;outputClass=com.xxx.Model"/>
```

This will return a List of Model. Model class is

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ";", generateHeaderColumns = true, crlf = "UNIX")
public class Model2 {

    @DataField(pos = 1, columnName = "A_Liererant")
    private String vendor;
    @DataField(pos = 2, columnName = "F_EAN")
    private String ean;
    @DataField(pos = 3, columnName = "G_Lief. Artikelnummer")
    private String itemId;
    @DataField(pos = 4, columnName = "H_Menge")
    private BigDecimal quantity;

    //getters setters
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot map all properties to bean of type class com.xxx.Model2. There are 1 unmapped properties. {itemid=11.0441-5402.2}
```

From my understanding the problem is in the naming of model properties. *One solution that I tried and worked is to rename the Model **itemId => itemid***. This will work, but i am not using Java naming conventions.

Do you know how to overcome this without renaming properties?

I also tried the following but it didn't work.

```
 @DataField(pos = 3, columnName = "G_Lief. Artikelnummer", name = "itemid")
    private String itemId;
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to do. Are you trying to read from a table and export its results to a CSV file? And you are getting this error above when the route is executed? Is my understanding correctly? If so, may I suggest another approach?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to read records from db and create a csv file. Error happens at jdbc execution. As mentioned in the description, it cannot map property **itemId**, so rename in model class to **itemid** is one possible solution, but i am asking if there is a way to use java name conventions without renaming property. Have you got something in mind?

Comment: You could use camel-sql. Take a look at my answer. Later I'll take a look at the camel-jdbc alternative to be closer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anything wrong with your code structure.

If what you want to accomplish is retrieving from a table and export its results to a CSV based on your `Model2` class, I may suggest using **camel-sql**. Could be something like:

```
@Override
protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            getContext().getComponent("sql", SqlComponent.class).setDataSource(db);
            BindyCsvDataFormat camelDataFormat = new BindyCsvDataFormat(Model2.class);

            from("sql:select vendor, ean, itemid as itemId, quantity from ElectronicDeliveryNotes?outputType=SelectList&outputClass=com....model.Model2")
                    .marshal(camelDataFormat)
                    .log("the body:\n${body}")
                    .to("mock:result");
        }
    };
}
```

You poll the data from the table, marshall it and then send the message to other queue. I've run some tests to make sure that the query results could be transformed into a CSV and as long as you keep the fields' name equals to your property, nothing seems to go wrong. (**side note**: in my tests even without the alias everything went fine).

But, testing your code, I went in the same error. Maybe you need to implement the `beanRowMapper`:

> To use a custom org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.BeanRowMapper when using outputClass. The default implementation will lower case the row names and skip underscores, and dashes. For example "CUST_ID" is mapped as "custId".

My guess this is the reason why you are stuck in this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot map all properties to bean of type class com.xxx.Model2. There are 1 unmapped properties. {itemid=11.0441-5402.2}
```

Try renaming your alias to `ITEM_ID`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! **beanRowMapper** is an option in jdbc component, so I have to povide a custom implementation, or as you said alias collumn to ITEM_ID, or just name java class property itemid.

Comment: Yeah! But if you accept a suggestion, I think only renaming your alias to ITEM_ID could be more reliable.

Comment: Yes there are 3 options, alias approach is as you said more reliable! Thanks again